# What does the errorFORBIDDEN popup mean on a https server while sending an ajax post to the server?

Tags: internet-explorer, https

On a https website, some operations like ajax posting to the server are performed.  For example:

```
$(".output").load("/server/ajax/", {client: 1234});
```

The above jQuery operation will perform a [POST](http://api.jquery.com/load/#request-method).

On the latest browsers like Firefox, Chrome and IE9, the above operation works with no issues.  I have even tried with IE8 without any problems.  However, there is a user on IE8 who's seeing the attached popup:

[image]

The above is in German. Is the English text `errorFORBIDDEN` the same for Windows EN?  If not what is the equivalent and why is that popup occurring on that's user's Win7, IE8 and not on mine?

Comment: Is the user using some kind of rewriting proxy or other tool (GreaseMonkey or similar) that would insert something like this?  Or some kind of flawed cross-site scripting detection?

Comment: I'm not sure, she's just a regular user using the default OS, browser at her office.

Comment: Do you have any authentication happening on the server?

Comment: Yes, the user should already be authenticated before getting to the page where she can perform the ajax post operation.